# What does it mean to keep a reference?

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, reference, widget

I am experimenting with widgets from Matplotlib and many of them, take for [example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.SpanSelector) `matplotlib.widgets.TextBox`, say in the docs:

> For the text box to remain responsive you must keep a reference to it.

What do they mean by "reference" and why is it needed?

I am not a newbie at Python but I still lack a lot of technical jargon. I would appreciate it if someone takes the time to shed some light on it, even if it is a basic question.

Comment: It means to assign it to a variable that stays in scope, ie `selector = SpanSelector(...)`

Comment: One definition for reference is: *the use of a source of information in order to ascertain something*. So in this case, you are storing information at a source (such as a variable) so that you can *reference* it later on. Meaning, if you want to update a text box, you need to be able to refer to that specific text box. So having a source of the information you can refer to allows you to manipulate that source for future reference, such as the text box text value and the changes to that value over the lifespan of the text box.